# How can I implement a theme in my maven archetype? (styles.css, styles.scss etc)

Tags: themes, maven-archetype

I'm implementing my own `Archetype` in `Maven`. I'm facing the problem of including a theme (with its `style.css` and `style.scss` etc). Its name is being chosen in the process of the generation. After generating the archetype, the theme and the whole folder in which it is located does not exist in the new project. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include an archetype descriptor which includes references to the file sets you want to include.

You can find how to structure this in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html).

In your case it will be something along the lines of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <archetype-descriptor name="project">
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet filtered="false" packaged="false">
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.scss</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes/>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
    </archetype-descriptor>
```

Your files should then be included under src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I only have to figure out why only one name works for my theme but I'm sure it will be a small change.